# Rachel and Andrew Lewdin are short with Norse God riddler (4, 6)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Here's another cryptic that I thought would be fun to make (and hopefully solve).

> Rachel and Andrew Lewdin are short with Norse God riddler (4, 6)

Enjoy!

Comment: You may enjoy the Cryptic Clue Chat Chains ("CCCC") thing that has been running for several years and a few thousand clues at this point, in Puzzling's chat room, [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair). It's a good place to stretch the cryptics muscles and try to solve a clue to earn the privilege of setting your own clue as the next challenge in the chain. (Setting individual clues as main site puzzles tends not to scale very well, as people tend to lose interest in serial single-clue puzzles from the same setter fairly quickly.)

Comment: @Rubio Thanks for the advice; I was beginning to wonder about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to go with

> the esteemed riddler [RAND AL'THOR](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)

Definition:

> riddler

Wordplay:

> R(achel) AND A(ndrew) L(ewdin) THOR

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess:

> Thor's Hammer?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, Charlie :) Unfortunately this doesn't have the same enumeration as the clue - it's (5,6) rather than (4,6) - so cannot be correct. Take a look at the accepted answer and you'll see how this was intended to work as a cryptic clue, with a definition part and a wordplay part - usually an answer to a cryptic clue question should have the wordplay explained. Take a look at some other questions in this tag to see. Welcome again, and Happy Puzzling :)

Comment: Spoiler markdown is `>!` at the beginning of line.